# Alghorithm for choosing the best set of words for twitter filtering

Tags: correlation, feature-selection, text-mining

I'm using the [twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter) to get a stream of tweets. You can't get all the tweets from the public API, it requires you to add some word filters. But you can add up to 400 words for filtering and if a tweet contains any of these 400 words it is returned to you.

I want to choose the 400 words that get me the max amount of tweets. For doing this twitter also provides you a stream with a small percentage of all the tweets randomly picked. My first idea was to use this list of sample tweets and get the 400 most used words, but this list of words have a lot of correlation.

What is the right way to get the 400 words from the sample stream, that get me the max amount of tweets from the filter API?

Comment: You probably can't go wrong by using the most common words in English.  The vast majority of sentences contain at least one of these words, and just the articles alone would cover most of them. For Twitter you might also want to include things like "RT".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English

Comment: That being said, some of the most common words may be explicitly excluded from search results; not sure though

Comment: yes, I am currently using the most common words on twitter, but that is not the optimal set of words to use as a filter (because of correlation between some words)

Comment: If you can get virtually all the tweets by using the most common words, why would you need a set of words that is provably optimal?

Comment: Well, maybe in addition to a frequency wordlist, you would need a frequency wordlist including correlations (or better, count of co-occurence). If one can find such a thing ...